# Python - I want to split a string into a list of string, by whitespaces. However, it's important to ignore certain parts of the string

Tags: python, regex

Consider the following string:

```
'128.000000 5.000000 2-level SCT3030AL C:\\Users\\Tex\\Desktop\\Test 2 do Project GUI - Opt - Copy\\Vectors\\Ripple = 0.3\\TwoLev9.6kHz_Ripple_0.3.txt 9600.000000'
```

I want to split it into the following form:

```
['128.000000', '5.000000',  '2-level', 'SCT3030AL', 'C:\\Users\\Tex\\Desktop\\Test 2 do Project GUI - Opt - Copy\\Vectors\\Ripple = 0.3\\TwoLev9.6kHz_Ripple_0.3.txt', '9600.000000']
```

Obs.:
The text is not always the same as this, but I want to split everything by whitespaces except what is in between ':' and 'txt'.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest would be to use `regex` (instead of `re`) as in

```
import regex as re

text = '128.000000 5.000000 2-level SCT3030AL C:\\Users\\Tex\\Desktop\\Test 2 do Project GUI - Opt - Copy\\Vectors\\Ripple = 0.3\\TwoLev9.6kHz_Ripple_0.3.txt 9600.000000'

rx = re.compile(r':.+?\.txt(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\s+')

parts = rx.split(text)
print(parts)
```

This yields

```
['128.000000', '5.000000', '2-level', 'SCT3030AL', 'C:\\Users\\Tex\\Desktop\\Test 2 do Project GUI - Opt - Copy\\Vectors\\Ripple = 0.3\\TwoLev9.6kHz_Ripple_0.3.txt', '9600.000000']
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/zQo6vA/1).

Comment: Is there any `re` equivalent?

Comment: @KenT: There is, you'd need to use the matched subgroups.

Comment: Do Can demonstrate how to use split in re to achieve the same?  I can’t figure out the pattern.